# How long is the idle timer?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In Old School RuneScape, you automatically get logged out after a certain period of inactivity. This is approximately a few minutes when not in combat, tens of minutes when in combat, and six hours no matter what. I was under the impression that the in-combat logout timer was 20 minutes, but after some accidental experimentation today, that appears not to be the case (I left a Nightmare Zone session running to go to a meeting, and about 40 minutes later I was still in combat and logged in).

How long can you remain logged on before being automatically logged out?

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape/comments/701s0u/logout_timer_in_combat_now/) reddit post says after 20mins of idle combat, your character just stops attacking while staying logged in. I have no way of confirming at the moment in time though...

Comment: @Wondercricket hmm that sounds right now that I think about it. I don't remember if I was attacking when I came back or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [version 1.9 of the Runelite client](https://runelite.net/blog/show/2022-10-05-1.9.0-Release), a logout timer plugin was added that will now extend your standard logout time up to 25 minutes.

Comment: What about Mobile?

Answer (score 6):

**Standard Logout**
After 5 minutes of non-combat inactivity, the game with automatically log you out.

**Extensive Logout**
After 6 hours, regardless of activity, the game will automatically log you out.

**Combat Logout**
After 20 minutes of inactivity while in combat, rather than logging you out, your character will stop automatically attacking the enemy. As a result, the enemy may lose aggression and eventually stop attacking you as well. Once the enemy loses aggression and stops attacking you, the standard idle timer will log you out.

If the enemies do **not** lose aggression, then you will remain logged despite exceeding the 20 minute mark. The Youtube video explains that he was able to stay logged in for over an hour while being inactive in the Nightmare zone because the enemies did not lose aggression and continued to attack.

**Sources**

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape/comments/701s0u/logout_timer_in_combat_now/)
- [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bthC-jDvu7E)
- [Logout wiki](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Logout_button)

Comment: I believe the alternative to the Combat Logout is if you die to whatever is attacking you, you log out once you respawn (or shortly after that).